# Microsoft Office Communicator randomly gets focus

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, office-communicator

After installing Visual Studio and SharePoint 2010, all our developers have been experiencing a problem with Office Communicator randomly activating its dialog window and taking the focus. It gets worse when your running the VS debugger. 
We have searched the web and found nothing about this issue. Has anyone heard of this problem or are we the only ones?

Answer (score 7):

I've been using VS/SharePoint/Communicator (and Lync) together for a few years now, and never noticed this problem.

I'd guess it comes from the integration between Team Explorer and Communicator - if you drop down the "Team Members" option under a project, you should see the presence of all users defined against that project.

If you're not using this integration (to be honest, it's never really added any value for me) then you can disable it by right-clicking the "Team Members" option, then selecting "Personal Settings". On the General tab under the Collaboration area, select "Change...", and choose "None" as the provider.

Otherwise, I'd suggest the not-too-sophisticated option of uninstalling and reinstalling communicator...